# jquery autocomplete returns [object Object]

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

I've been beating my head against the wall trying to get this work.  I'm not very good at this so i'm sure i'm missing something simple.  I have searched the knowledgebase but i haven't found something that helps and i'm pretty sure there's a better way of accomplishing this.

I'm trying to have my input field autocomplete but it returns [object Object].  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

jquery:

```
<script>
$('#client_id').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/slips/suggest',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
               user_input: request.term
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item,
                        value: item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 3
});
  </script>
```

json output:

```
[{"label":"Doe, John","value":"1"},{"label":"Doe, Jane","value":"2"},{"label":"Doe, Jack","value":"3"},{"label":"Doe, Jake","value":"4"},{"label":"Doe, Jim","value":"5"}]
```

html:

```
<div style="height: 20px;float: left;display: inline-block;padding-top:15px;">
<span class="new_slip">Client</span>
<input type="text" id="client_id" name="client_id" style="width:100px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Each `item` in the `$.map()` is an `Object`, which becomes `"[object Object]"` when made into a string. The `$.map()` isn't really necessary since the `data` is already in the structure expected.

Comment: ah ok.  so then what should it look like? this?
     success: function( data ) {
      response();
    }

Comment: i got it.  changed to       response(data);
thanks Jonathan

Comment: It could be as simple as `success: response` if you don't need to adjust the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` provided in the response is already in [one of the structures that `.autocomplete()` expects](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> - **Array**
>
>   - ...
>   - An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

So, the `$.map()` isn't necessary, in this case.

```
// ...
success: response
// ...
```

---

The `[object Object]` you're seeing is the default `.toString()` result for `Object`s.

```
console.log({}.toString());
// "[object Object]"
```

And, comes from assigning each `item`, which are all `Object`s, as the `label` and `value`:

```
var data = [ {"label":"Doe, John","value":"1"} ];

data = $.map( data, function ( item ) {
    return {
        label: item,
        value: item
    }
});

console.log(data);
/*
[
    {
        label: { label: "Doe, John", value: 1 },
        value: { label: "Doe, John", value: 1 }
    }
]
*/
```